# MobX how to make imported component observable?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

In my code I am using external library for rendering table its called antd.
I want to re render this imported component when my store state changes but I am unable to make this component observable as its is imported component and it uses data passed as props.

It only worked when I also rendered this store data in main component so it triggered re rendering also this child imported componeent. But don't want to return this data in the main component i want to only return it in the table.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table } from 'antd';

@inject('meetingsStore')
@observer
export default class MeetingNotes extends React.Component {

 render() {
    const meetingsStore = this.props.meetingsStore;
    const { agendaPoints } = meetingsStore.getCurrentMeeting();

    return (
      <Table
        rowKey="id"
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={agendaPoints}
        pagination={false}
      />
    );
  }

}
```

When I update the store state I want this Table component to re-render.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by using mobx toJS

Here is an example working code if someone will face a similar issue.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Table } from 'antd';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { toJS } from 'mobx';

@inject('meetingsStore')
@observer
export default class MeetingNotes extends React.Component {

 render() {
    const meetingsStore = this.props.meetingsStore;
    const { agendaPoints } = meetingsStore.getCurrentMeeting();

    return (
      <Table
        rowKey="id"
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={toJS(agendaPoints)}
        pagination={false}
      />
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that React components work with Mobx, they should be completely rebuilt for this library. [Observer components if they are directly accessed by render](https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html#mobx-only-tracks-data-accessed-for-observer-components-if-they-are-directly-accessed-by-render). Look a similar problem in my question 
[Ant-Design Table not rendering when change state in mobx store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62261679/ant-design-table-not-rendering-when-change-state-in-mobx-store)