# Ant-Design Table not rendering when change state in mobx store

Tags: reactjs, antd, mobx

I program the behavior of clicking on a row in the ant design Table component. This should change the rowClassName on the Table. [Here is an example on CodeSendBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-frost-3job9?file=/Table.jsx). When you click on a table row, the value in the Store.selectedRowKey changes, but the table is not re rendering. If you move the dividing slider to the sandbox and the table size changes, then rendering occurs and a new row selection is applied

Here's another example, where mobx don't work with ant-design Table

[Ant Design Table with Modal form CRUD](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-gates-9mgpc)

I'm new in the Mobx
I really want to understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: To re-render the ant design table I use the hook explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240647/react-how-to-force-a-function-component-to-render

Answer (score 8):

To re-render an Ant-Design table, you have to pass the data-source value as a clone of the observable value.

you have to change

```
<Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={values}
/>
```

to the following code:

```
<Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={[...values]}
/>
```

Comment: @Nechama can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: Seems inefficient performance-wise, but that was the only way it worked for me, too

Comment: @miles.sherman Ant table is rerendered only if dataSource is a new object. In your case the object is the same

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine that people are still looking for answers specially with the newest version of antd.

So in Antd version 5.x table API, you could find a property call `rowKey`.

In version 4.0 table API, the property called `key` thou.

And to way to tackle the problem correctly is to set it like following:

```
<Table
  columns={columns}
  dataSource={data}
  rowKey={data.key} />
```

Note: Please consider to have a key property in your array of course. key must be unique.

Comment: I just logged in with a different browser (in which I use stack overflow) to give you a vote up. ;) Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't use `selectedRowKey` inside your observer component, so that's why it does not rerender when it changes.

You pass a callback function to a `Table` but `Table` is not observer.

I am not sure if it possible to make it observer in `antd`, but what else you can do:

1) Just use `selectedRowKey` inside your render somewhere. Like just `console.log` it and then your whole component will rerender (including the Table) when row is clicked.

Or better way, mix it with `data` rows, for example add `isSelected` key for each data for inside render and change `rowClassName` to use this flag:

```
dataSource={data.map(item => ({...item, isSelected: this.props.Store.selectedRowKey === item.key}))}
rowClassName={x => x.isSelected ? 'test-table-row-selected' : ''}
```

2) Use `antd` `rowSelection` prop like that `rowSelection={{selectedRowKeys: [selectedRowKey]}}`. But it will also add checkboxes to each row.